# Using \cal font in LateX2e. Is it possible?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, amsmath, mathcal

I've been searching far and wide to try and find a solution to this but no luck yet -

I have to create a table which looks similar to this but with a few changes: [image: Categories of Syntax of WTT]

and I was told the source uses something like this:

`atomic & $\it variables$ & $V = V^{\cal T} |V^{\mathbb S}| V^{\cal S} $ & $x$ \\`
to achieve the first row, starting with atomic.

But `\cal` seems to not work, and `\mathcal` does not match this font style.

So is there a way to get around this?

[Here](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~fairouz/forest/papers/journals-publications/kjour.pdf) is the pdf file for the journal I'm working from.

Comment: Welcome! A complete example we can compile would be much more useful than a mere fragment. Don't say `$\it variables$`, though. `\it` is 20+ years obsolete. Maybe you want `$\mathit{variables}$` though I'm not clear why you want maths mode at all rather than `\textit{variables}`. If the table is from a PDF, check the fonts it is using. This will likely help you identify the one you are trying to find.

Comment: you're using plain tex command names for fonts.  you tried `\mathcal` instead of `\cal`, which is the proper thing to do, but if the style of the font doesn't match, then a different font was used in the original.  checking the list of alphabets in the "comprehensive symbol list" (`texdoc comprehensive`), it looks like euler script `\usepackage{euscript}` is close, but not exact.  use the suggestion by @cfr if this is from a pdf file.

Comment: do you have the original document as PDF? If so you can use acrobat or pdfonts utility to list the fonts being used. From a bitmap image as here it's harder.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have edited the question to include the link for the pdf.

Comment: @cfr The source I am working with is from 1997! I know about those changes - but just struggling with the font because `\cal`and `\mathcal` fonts are not the same

Comment: Fair enough. It was the `something like` which made me think this was reverse engineering in which case they'd be no reason to use obsolete code.

Comment: Note that how the PDF appears to you is not determined entirely by the PDF as not all the fonts are embedded. It is using Zapf Chancery which is embedded. It also has a whole bunch of fonts whose names appear to be `[n/a]` and are embedded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `lualatex` or `xelatex` you can choose the math font for each range separately using `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\section{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{equation}
  \symtt{V}=\symtt{V}^{\symcal{T}} \abs*{\symtt{V}^\symbb{S}}\symtt{V}^{\symcal{S}}
\end{equation}

\section{XITS Math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range={cal, bfcal, bb}]
\begin{equation}
  \symtt{V}=\symtt{V}^{\symcal{T}} \abs*{\symtt{V}^\symbb{S}}\symtt{V}^{\symcal{S}}
\end{equation}

\section{XITS Math – \texttt{StylisticSet=1}}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range={cal, bfcal, bb}, StylisticSet=1]
\begin{equation}
  \symtt{V}=\symtt{V}^{\symcal{T}} \abs*{\symtt{V}^\symbb{S}}\symtt{V}^{\symcal{S}}
\end{equation}

\section{Asana Math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[range={cal, bfcal, bb}]
\begin{equation}
  \symtt{V}=\symtt{V}^{\symcal{T}} \abs*{\symtt{V}^\symbb{S}}\symtt{V}^{\symcal{S}}
\end{equation}

\section{Tex Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Termes Math}[range={cal, bfcal, bb}]
\begin{equation}
  \symtt{V}=\symtt{V}^{\symcal{T}} \abs*{\symtt{V}^\symbb{S}}\symtt{V}^{\symcal{S}}
\end{equation}

\section{Cambria Math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[range={cal, bfcal, bb}]
\begin{equation}
  \symtt{V}=\symtt{V}^{\symcal{T}} \abs*{\symtt{V}^\symbb{S}}\symtt{V}^{\symcal{S}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

To me, it looks like the `mtpro2` ([MathTime Professional 2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html)) font package was used to create the table. Specifically, it looks like the package was loaded with the options `mtpcal` for a Times-compatible Math Script font and `mtphrb` for a Times-compatible blackboard bold font. Not as sure about the monospaced font that's in use, but `Courier` would appear to be a fairly close match.

Note that the full `mtpro2` package, which provides the special math fonts, is not free of charge.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{ptm} % Times text font
\renewcommand\ttdefault{pcr} % Courier (monospaced font)
\usepackage[mtpcal,mtphrb]{mtpro2} % Times math fonts

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lllc}
level& Main & abstract syntax & Meta-\\
& category & & symbol\\[2ex]
atomic&
\emph{variables} &
$\texttt{V}=\texttt{V}^{\mathcal{T}} \abs{\texttt{V}^\mathbb{S}}\texttt{V}^{\mathcal{S}}$ &  $x$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great but and gives me exactly what I'm looking for but I think paying so much for it would possibly be my last option.
Also, I only need it for that table I mentioned in the question - seems a shame to pay that much just for that.

Answer (score 1):

running pdffonts on the supplied pdf produces

```
$ pdffonts kjour.pdf  | grep -v '\[none\]'
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Times-Italic                         Type 1            Custom           no  no  no      12  0
Times-Bold                           Type 1            Standard         no  no  no      13  0
Times-Roman                          Type 1            Custom           no  no  no       8  0
Courier                              Type 1            Standard         no  no  no      11  0
Symbol                               Type 1            Symbol           no  no  no      38  0
QPYQCX+ZapfChancery-MediumItalic     Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      54  0
```

so presumably it's ZapfChancery you are after.

Probably this obsolete package

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pzccal

or you could use

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/urwchancal

the `\cal` or `\mathcal` distinction is not relevant here, the latex syntax has been `\mathcal` since latex2e came out in 1993, `\cal` is plain TeX syntax for the same thing.

Comment: The supplied PDF has Zapf Chancery, but the shown image is quite different. I guess the image uses proprietary fonts and is from the published version, whereas the PDF file is a revised version using free fonts.

Comment: @egreg quite possibly, and just using computer modern \mathcal conveys the same meaning!